# TCL man page: it is better to place comment section way ahead

Tags: tcl

I know I am really picky here, but like to throw it out in case I am off in my interpreting the TCL [man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), actually, I wish I was wrong here, as you see the below story.

So for every new TCL developer, we recommend reading the famous "11 rules" (now it is 12 rules).

Yesterday I was asked this question: why does the following script fail?

```
# puts "hello
world!"
```

Of course it fails, I said, the first line is taken as comment, that leaves `world!"` as a command.

But, the newbie said, the manpage indicates that the script is parsed in certain order:

1. As [#2 Evaluation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M6) states, the command is parsed to words first.
2. As [#4 Double quotes](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8) states, newline is taken as is in parsing double quotes. This makes `hello` and `world!` into one word, with a newline in between.
3. [Comments at #10](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M30) does states everything up till the next newline is ignored, but after the above processing, the newline should be the 2nd newline, the one after `world!`.

I see he had a point.

It makes more sense to move the comment section way ahead in the man page, maybe at the second section. With this order change, it indicates that comment recognition is preceding the word-tokenizing process.

How do you think?

Again, I have no intention to ask for change of the manpage, just want to make sure if I miss anything in interpreting the bible.

[**UPDATE**]
To the people suggesting to close this question as not-a-technical question, it is the same as if my colleague came here asking why that script fails even though his understanding of TCL man page indicates it is a good script.

Again, I am not asking to change the man page.

Let me re-phrase my question - when you are asked this same question, what flaw do you see in his reasoning?

**[UPDATE2]**
Thanks Donal. I think this is what I learnt, TCL parser goes one char by another, there is no look-ahead.

This is another example:

```
puts [#haha]
```

Such script fails at tclsh for the same reason, TCL parser does not break down the script first and only parses the string embedded inside the matching brackets, instead it recognizes "#" as the start of comment and ignores everything after it.

Comment: The biggest problem is that `#` is not a command, but starts a comment. An other example would `# foo [bar]` - `bar` is not called. If `#` would be a command, then it would evaluate `[bar]` first.

Comment: Also note, that the description of comments says "If a hash character (`#`) appears at a point where Tcl is expecting the first character of the first word of a command then the hash character and the characters that follow it, up through the next newline, are treated as a comment and ignored." - as we already saw, a comment is not a command. I agree, the point 1. (defines a Tcl script) could include comments.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for change of the tcl project and is not a question that will have a technical solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules in the Tcl(n) manual page describe pretty precisely the parser that Tcl uses. Requests to change it substantively are usually denied as they tend to have far-reaching consequences and interact with each other trickily. Verifying that a reordering of the rules is not substantive is a non-trivial task, as they correspond to quite a bit of code (our parser and a chunk of our bytecode compiler).

Adding non-normative sections (e.g., EXAMPLES) is easier.

---

### Update based on your updated question

The problem with the reasoning is that the rules are a *whole*, not really a layered set of parts. They do interact with each other. (The one that usually trips people up is the interaction between the brace rule and the comment rule *when inside a braced string* such as a procedure body.) Comments really are true comments, and extend up to the end of the line (allowing for backslash-newline sequences) but not beyond, but they only start at places where commands start, not at other places with a `#` character, and that's the genuinely tricky bit.

Unfortunately, the way that the Tcl parser works is a bit different to the way that programmers think, but most of the time it's pretty good at pretending to work in a “reasonable fashion”. The tricky edge cases don't actually come up too often other than when dealing with the brace-comment interaction mentioned above. The other cases which I hit tend to be either with a `switch` (resolvable by just putting the comment in the arm) or with long literal lists of things where I want to comment some sections of the list; in that latter case, I actually post-process the string before using it as a list.

```
set exampleList {
    a b c
    d e f
    # Not really a comment but I want to use it like one!
    g h i
    j k l
}
# Convert “comment” lines to empty lines
regsub -all -line "^\\s*#.*$" $exampleList "" exampleList
```

The general advantage of Tcl's rules is that it is actually pretty easy to embed other languages within Tcl, precisely because Tcl only treats `#` (and other character) as special in well-defined contexts. As long as you can have the embedded language be one that uses balanced braces — and that's almost all of them in practice — then embedding it is utterly trivial. The other cases have to use backslashes and/or double quotes and are pretty ugly, but are also a minuscule fraction of all the embedding cases.

Your colleague's problem is that he's looking at the whole script in one go, whereas the Tcl parser handles one character at a time and doesn't do meaningful amounts of lookahead. It's just some dumb code.

Comment: I guess I could have done a better answer before, but my train was arriving at the station…